# Bar (created as a CALayer) height/bounds animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer

I have created a chart which contains bars (`CALayer`). They have a text on top and bottom of them (`CATextLayer`). Now I want to add some animation to bars (make them increase from the bottom to top).

Here is the code that I have now (this method creates bars and adds it to the main layer (`mainLayer`)):

```
 private func drawBar(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, color: UIColor? = .gray) {
    let initialBound = CGRect(x: xPos, y: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace, width: barWidth, height: 0)
    let finalBound = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)
    let increaseBar = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
    increaseBar.fromValue = initialBound
    increaseBar.toValue = finalBound
    increaseBar.duration = 2.0

    let barLayer = CALayer()

    barLayer.frame = finalBound
    barLayer.cornerRadius = 20
    barLayer.backgroundColor = color?.cgColor
    barLayer.add(increaseBar, forKey: nil)
    mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
}
```

Here are the properties used:

```
  //Width of each bar
let barWidth: CGFloat = 40.0

//Space between each bar
let space: CGFloat = 20.0


//Space at the bottom of the bar to show the title
private let bottomSpace: CGFloat = 40.0

//Space at the top of each bar to show the value
private let topSpace: CGFloat = 40.0
```

`xPos` and `yPos` are found in this way (`index` is just an `Int` which increases in a `for in` loop from zero to the number of entries, and in this case, it is equal to `1`):

```
      /// Starting x postion of the bar
     let xPos: CGFloat = space + CGFloat(index) * (barWidth + space)

    /// Starting y postion of the bar
    let yPos: CGFloat = translateHeightValueToYPosition(value: entry.height)
```

`entry.height` is just some arbitrary number between `0.0` and `1.0`. Here is the definition of `translateHeightValueToYPosition(value:)` method:

```
 private func translateHeightValueToYPosition(value: Float) -> CGFloat {

    let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(value) * (mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - topSpace)
    return mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - height
}
```

Now, everything works fine except the bars animation starts from the middle of their total height. I've tried to change the value for `yPos` (manually) but without a success. I have also tried to animate bar's `height`, by initially setting it to `0`, but again, without success.

Here is how the animation looks like:

[image]

How to make bars increase from bottom towards the top, instead of the middle of their height? I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, the only problem with the layer's anchorPoint. the default anchorPoint is set to CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) which is middle. So you just need to change them.

for the top: CGPoint.zero

for the bottom : CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)

Here is the right code for only one correction:

```
private func drawBar(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, color: UIColor? = .gray) {
let initialBound = CGRect(x: xPos, y: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace, width: barWidth, height: 0)
let finalBound = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)
let increaseBar = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
increaseBar.fromValue = initialBound
increaseBar.toValue = finalBound
increaseBar.duration = 2.0

let barLayer = CALayer()
// my code line
barLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
barLayer.frame = finalBound
barLayer.cornerRadius = 20
barLayer.backgroundColor = color?.cgColor
barLayer.add(increaseBar, forKey: nil)
mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
```

}

Hope my answer will solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's funny that because of that one line of code  I was almost going crazy :)

Comment: :) All the best for your code!